# Exported excel file from datagridview shows error when opened VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I'm doing an export in VB. I was able to export the values of the datagridview to excel but when I open the file, it shows this error.

[image: Error]

I'm using the following code to export the values of the datagridview.

```
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim sPath As String = String.Empty
    Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xls"
    dlgSave.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xls"

    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


        For i = 0 To dgvFile.RowCount - 1
            For j = 0 To dgvFile.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To dgvFile.Columns.Count
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvFile.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvFile(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        Dim sFileName As String = Replace(dlgSave.FileName, ".xlsx", ".xlx")

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(sFilename)
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        Dim res As MsgBoxResult
        res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
            Process.Start(sFileName)
        End If
    End If
```

**NOTE**
This code works fine. It exports the values without any problem. It just shows the error when I open the excel file. **The exported file has no problem when I click "Yes". It shows the correct values**. I just want this error to stop showing when I open the file.

Can anyone help me fix this solution? I will be truly grateful to anyone who can lead me. Thanks. :)

Comment: try saving in `.xls` format.it may be problem with excel version in you computer.

Comment: I tried saving to .xls but it still shows the error. The problem is with the format just like what you said. My Excel uses .xlsx so it needs to be saved into .xlsx. This was sorted. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks to akhil kumar.

My Excel uses .xlsx extension so I changed

```
dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xls"
```

to

`dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xlsx"`

and removed the Replace function to make it look like this.

```
Dim sFileName As String = dlgSave.FileName
```

This works perfectly. This problem was sorted. :)